# Ansible or Jenkins pipelines for bigger jobs

Tags: jenkins, ansible, devops

At the moment we are using combination of Jenkins pipelines and Ansible playbooks. Usually we end up with short ansible playbooks that are run either inside of Jenkins pipeline or just as a jenkins job.

What would be be better approach for more complicated, multi-step jobs?

For example one job consists of:

1. Start ec2 instance from AMI
2. Run migrations
3. Pull latest code, compile and restart
4. Create new AMI from temporary instance
5. Terminate temporary instance

I do like the fact that I can handle user input in Jenkins pipelines as well as the graphic representation of every step in the pipeline. In example above each step would be probably its own little ansible playbook. Passing parameters from playbook to playbook isnt that straight forward, but we know how to do it.

I am not 100% sure if I am doing this up to best standard as during creating these pipelines I am thinking that this should probably be ansible and the other way around.

Is there any sweet spot how to use these two together?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you are indeed well aware of the limitations that each tool brings to the table,

The sweet spot would be what works the best for you and your company, now, ask yourself which approach would be easier to manage? which one would become too complicated when scaling?

I've done both approaches and found that the pipeline tools from jenkins seem to have the best effect in terms of "readability" and ease of management, this is specially evident when we had the chance to bring new members on the team and they can get a quick overview of the processes just by looking at our pipelines on jenkins,

Now, we have also used a combination of jenkins (just ci) + nexus (artifact management) + octopus (just cd) + ansible (provisioning) to handle everything on complicated pipelines,

Again, ask yourself what would be easier to manage, and what is most likely to grow over time (number of steps on the pipeline, number of pipelines or jobs, number of servers to manage, etc...) and take a decision based on that,

Best Regards,

Comment: Yeah I thought its not going to be straight forward answer. I definitely like to use ansible for things like deployment, architecture management etc purely because its plugins and ease of connecting to scalable instances. But pipelines seem to be better choice for "orchestrating" the whole process

Comment: Exactly, even then you could just have stuff like a dynamic inventory and have a step on a jenkins pipeline to provision the whole fleet of servers. You could also look into release management tools, i haven't really found an alternative to octopus deploy in ease of use, and the fact that it helps your team get a higher level view of the process, that way you know which environment is in which state and can easily reproduce older releases and roll back in a safer way!

Comment: Almost finished the pipeline I was originally writing, definitely learned a lot. Ansible and Jenkins documentation... oh boy... I did see octopus before but I think we dismissed it because it was too expensive

Comment: it is free for small projects, however, i totally fell in love with it the MINUTE i tried it, the fact that you deal in "releases" which are just instances of the executions of a pipeline makes the process so much more easy to trace! i.e. you changed  something in your pipeline, deployed it and it broke something. You can just click the release that was deployed before that and octopus will execute the pipeline the EXACT same way it did on that earlier release, it persists even variables!

Comment: oh, and jenkins can create and trigger releases/deployments on it too, so the integration can be however you want!